# How do I activate the C# Omnisharp server in VSCode for .NET development? Currently, in VSCode for C#, IntelliSense isn't working

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, omnisharp

I started working on a .NET project in VSCode from WSL, and I have installed all the necessary extensions, including C# and the C# development kit. However, in my .NET code, I'm not seeing any IntelliSense, and I also cannot navigate to the implementation of functions using F12. Furthermore, when I search for Omnisharp in the VSCode command palette, it doesn't appear. I feel completely in the dark.

Comment: Open the output panel, select C# from the dropdown, check if there's any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem. This occurred because the new version of the C# extension has disabled the OmniSharp server by default. Therefore, we need to manually enable it. [image]

Then, search for Omnisharp and enable "Use Omnisharp," and my problem is solved. (Credit to : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dvRAT2H0emQ )

[image]